# nasm equivalent to set instruction

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

Does anyone know if nasm has an equivalent to the "set" instruction I am accustomed to using it so set bits in eax based on the result of a cmp but nasm doesn't seem to recognize it just wondering if there is an alternative to using xor and shifts to figuring out the results of a cmp.  I am trying to do something like the following

```
cmp eax,ecx
setl al
movzbl al,eax
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If not nasm, which assembler are you accustomed to using? Also, what exactly is the instruction you are trying to use?

Comment: I usually just use gcc I am trying something like the following to set eax = 1
    cmp eax,ecx
    sl
    movzbl ax,eax

Comment: NASM doesn't have any problems with `cmp eax,ecx`. You're being asked about that "set" thing.

Comment: @alexey 

I never said that it did

Comment: `SETcc Set byte to one on condition` so I believe it complains on `ax` usage

Comment: yeah sorry that was a typo I fixed the code in the question

Comment: and `movzbl` is actually `movzx`?

Answer (score 1):

This assembles just fine with NASM 2.10 from Mar 12 2012:

```
; file: set.asm
bits 16

cmp ecx, eax
setl al
movzx eax, al
```

I assemble it as `nasm -f bin set.asm`.

**EDIT**: I have reversed the order of operands everywhere as it seems like you were writing your code with the AT&T syntax in mind (not applicable to NASM), where the operands are in the reverse order.